# Get a list of users with a permission annotated as boolean

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to build a query to get a list of users with a boolean stating if they have a specific permission without the need to loop through the users and checking if they have the permission one by one

Below is a sample code, any way to change this into a query?

```
users = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=False)
permission = Permission.objects.get(codename=“codename”)
data = []
for i in users:
    data.append({“username”: i.username, “permission”: i.has_perm(permission)})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {key: bol for key in users}
```

I used dict comprehension to set the `bol` as the value of every user object which i set as key. So now the `data` is a dict with keys as users and value(same for everyone) as `bol`.

Comment: Im afraid you are misunderstanding my question. I want a list of users with a boolean if they have a specific permission.

Comment: That means you are not storing that boolean and that is just written in your program and you want to filter on that basis. Am i right?

Comment: There was never any intention to filter. I want a full list of users with an annotation stating if they have a specific permission as a boolean.

Comment: But you must be storing something against which we will filter. What i mean is as you are not storing any additional data, how can we distinguish two users and give permission to one and not other. Also please upload your code.

Comment: My answer will return all users mapped with the bool

Comment: Once again I emphasise that I want to build a single query.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.